# Which object should I mock?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, repository-pattern

I am writing a [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Fetching objects is done through a DAO. Creating and updating objects is done through a Request object, which is given to a RequestHandler object (a la [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)). I didn't write the DAO, Request, or RequestHandler, so I can't modify them.

I'm trying to write a test for this repository. I have mocked out both the DAO and RequestHandler. My goal is to have the mocked RequestHandler simply add the new or updated object to the mocked DAO. This will create the illusion that I'm talking to the DB. This way, I don't have to mock the repository for all the classes that call this repository.

The problem is that the Request object is this gob of string blobs and various alphanumeric codes. I'm pretty sure XML is involved too. It's sort of a mess. Another developer is writing the code to create the Request object based on the objects being stored. And since RequestHandler takes in Requests and not the object I'm storing, it can't update the mocked DAO.

So the question is: do I mock the Request too, or should I wait until the other guy, who is kind of slow, to finish his code before I write the test? Or screw it and mock out the entire repository when testing the classes that call the repository?

BTW, I say "mock" not in the NMock sense, but rather like faking the DB with an in-memory collection.

Answer (score 2):

To test the repository I would suggest that you use test doubles for all of the lower layer objects.

To test the classes that depend on the repository I would suggest that you use test doubles for the repository.

In both cases I mean test doubles created by some mocking library (fakes where that works for the test, stubs where you need to return something to the object under test and mocks if you really have to).

If you are creating an implementation of the DAO using in-memory collections to functionally replace the database in a demo or test system that is different to unit testing the upper layers. I have done something similar so that I can give prototypes to people and concentrate on business objects not the physical model. That isn't for unit testing though.

Answer (score 0):

You may of may not be creating a web application, but you can have a look at the NerdDinner application which uses Repository.  It is a free PDF that explains how to create an application using ASP.NET MVC and can be found here: [Professional ASP.NET MVC 2.0](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html)